# Adding fields to pdf files using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-cell

I am a newbee to solr.I am having a problem with adding fields/metadata to pdf files while indexing them in solr using the ContentStreamUpdateRequest.As the literal parameter must be used to add fields I tried the following:

```
public static void indexFilesSolrCell(String fileName,String solrId,int i,String name,String Category,String loc,String locat) 
                    throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    //...
    ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
    File f1 = new File(fileName);
    up.addFile(new File(fileName));
    up.setParam("literal.id",solrId);
    up.setParam("literal.name",name );
    up.setParam("literal.url_file", loc);
    up.setParam("literal.location",locat);
    up.setParam("literal.Category",Category);
    //..
}
```

The pdf file gets indexed in solr but the problem is that **Not** all the fields have been created using literals.The following fields have been created:

1. **id**
2. **name**
3. **Category**.

   While it does not create fields like **url_file** or anything like **path** or **location**.**At times** it does not create the field *Category*.

   As of what I have gone through, any random field could be created using the literal parameter to create a metadata.Why is that fields like **id** or **name** or even **blah_s** are created always but when I try a random field like the above mentioned,solr does not create?
    Do we have to declare these random fields anywhere else as well?

   Any help is greatly appreciated.

   Update: Doesn't calling the method up.setParam("literal.myField") modify the schema.xml to create a new field?

Comment: How does your `schema.xml` look like?

Comment: I have actually used the example that is provided in the apache solr3.5.0 by importing its war. and I have noticed that only those fieldss that are defined in this xml file can be used with "literal".I was not able to find the "schema.xml" file but I could access it in the browser through the schema.jsp: http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml. How can I modify the schema.xml? The following were the fields that wre already defined: id,category,name and many other fields that I am not using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using the solr examples, which doesn't contain the `url_file` and `location` fields. You can find the `schema.xml` under `example/solr/conf`. I suggest you to clean it up a little keeping only the fields you need, since that schema contains a lot of fields you don't really need.

The blah_s field gets created because the schema you're using contains the following definition:

```
<dynamicField name="*_s" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

It's a dynamic field with suffix `_s`, it means every field with that suffix will be taken by Solr as `string`, `indexed` and `stored` as well.

To modify the `schema.xml` you need to open it locally and make changes to the xml file, then reload Solr. Remember that after a schema change you need to reindex, re-running the code you pasted in your question.